# Drawing Transparent Images

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, png, transparency

I'm writing a CSS sprite engine in C#, however I'm having a few issues. I create the master image, set all the properties to that then iterate the `sprites` and draw those to the master image. However when I come to save the master image it only appears to be just the empty master image with transparent background and none of the `sprites`. I'm very confused at where I'm going wrong.

The code I'm using is:

```
    // Work out the width/height required
    int max_width = 0;
    int max_height = 0;

    foreach(SpriteInformation sprite in sprites) {
        if (max_width < (sprite.Left + greatest_width)) max_width = sprite.Left + greatest_width;
        if (max_height < (sprite.Top + greatest_height)) max_height = sprite.Top + greatest_height;
    }

    // Create new master bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(max_width,max_height,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    // Set background color
    SolidBrush brush;

    if (cbxBackground.Checked) {
        if (txtColor.Text == "") {
            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        } else {
            brush = new SolidBrush(pnlColor.BackColor);
        }
    } else {
        if (txtColor.Text == "") {
            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        } else {
            brush = new SolidBrush(pnlColor.BackColor);
        }
    }

    //graphics.FillRectangle(brush,0,0,bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height);
    bitmap.MakeTransparent(brush.Color);
    graphics.Clear(brush.Color);

    // Copy images into place
    ImageAttributes attr = new ImageAttributes();

    //attr.SetColorKey(brush.Color,brush.Color);

    foreach(SpriteInformation sprite in sprites) {
        Rectangle source = new Rectangle(0,0,sprite.Width,sprite.Height);
        Rectangle dest = new Rectangle(sprite.Left,sprite.Top,sprite.Width,sprite.Height);

        graphics.DrawImage(sprite.Sprite,dest,0,0,sprite.Width,sprite.Height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel,attr);
    }

    // Save image
    string format = ddlFormat.Items[ddlFormat.SelectedIndex].ToString();

    if (format == "PNG") {
        dlgSave.Filter = "PNG Images|*.png|All Files|*.*";
        dlgSave.DefaultExt = ",png";

        if (dlgSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            bitmap.Save(dlgSave.FileName,ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    } else if (format == "JPEG") {

    } else {

    }
```

Comment: As a warning IE6 doesn't support alpha transparency in pngs unless you use an 8 bit png.... Unfortunately System.Drawing won't let you output 8 bit pngs in an intelligent way. (It's not smart about picking the correct colors)

Comment: I was aware of IE6's limitations, bit annoying really. I saw some stuff on GIF color quantization I could probably apply to this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are sprite.Left and Top? If they aren't 0 that may be a problem. I think you have dest and source the wrong way round?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142045.aspx

Try a simpler DrawImage variant if you haven't already.
e.g. `DrawImage(sprite.Sprite,0,0)`

Comment: The sprite.Left/Top gives the coords where to draw the image on the final image. I've tried with DrawImage(sprite.Sprite,0,0) and DrawImage(sprite.Sprite,sprite.Left,sprite.Top) to no avail. I am certain the sprite.Sprite is assigned too because they're just loaded from another PNG and not touched.

Comment: :/ I see now. When you are calculating the maximum size of the bitmap, why do you use greatestwidth/height instead of the actual sprite size? Just grasping at straws here I'm afraid. I would try resetting all of those offsets to 0 and rendering onto a large image, just to make sure it's rendering into the area of the target image you think it is. Then you can add the offsets back in.

Comment: Yeh I'll try that next. The greatest width/height is basically the furthest offset+n required for a sprite so that I know how big the image is going to have to be.

Comment: OK got it working by moving the MakeTransparent, the issue is now the alpha of the source sprites does not seem to keep.

Answer (score -1):

You draw to "graphics", but then then you save "bitmap"? I'm not sure if that graphics internally works with your original "bitmap" object...

Comment: That does appear to be the implication in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx